# signing of datablock as hash in erlang not working. Key derivation based on ec

Tags: hash, cryptography, erlang, sign, elliptic-curve

Erlang version: 9.2

I am trying to sign one datablock with generated keys on ecdh-base.

Here is my workflow:

```
86> {PublicKey, PrivKeyOut} = crypto:generate_key(ecdh, crypto:ec_curve(secp521r1)).
{<<4,0,196,6,85,178,189,234,231,13,82,152,96,162,92,163,
   133,81,42,147,168,146,138,226,15,80,127,228,...>>,
 <<1,33,215,135,89,40,35,40,104,14,217,153,78,62,53,83,
   198,165,84,30,135,159,218,82,47,102,204,...>>}
87> Mesage = "testmessage".
"testmessage"
88> Hash = crypto:hash(sha512, Mesage).
<<1,216,98,78,245,111,176,233,114,224,249,27,118,114,49,
  189,40,144,90,249,175,108,79,235,186,247,247,40,131,...>>
89> Signature = crypto:sign(ecdsa, sha512, Hash, PrivKeyOut).
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  crypto:pkey_sign_nif/5
        called as crypto:pkey_sign_nif(ecdsa,sha512,
                                       <<1,216,98,78,245,111,176,233,114,224,
                                         249,27,118,114,49,189,40,144,90,249,
                                         175,108,79,235,186,247,...>>,
                                       <<1,33,215,135,89,40,35,40,104,14,217,
                                         153,78,62,53,83,198,165,84,30,135,159,
                                         218,82,47,...>>,
                                       [])
     in call from crypto:sign/5 (crypto.erl, line 433)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you try `ecdsa` insetad of `ecdh` when generating the key? Although the parameters and key should be identical, it might be that the API doesn't want to combine both. Also note that ECDSA requires the message itself as input: hashing is performed *internally*. Currently you are double-hashing the input message.

Comment: This is  result on my terminal:

    {PublicKey, PrivKeyOut} = crypto:generate_key(ecdsa, crypto:ec_curve(secp521r1)).
    ** exception error: no function clause matching 
                        crypto:generate_key(ecdsa,
                                            {{prime_field,
                                              <<1,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,
      ....
                                             <<1>>},
                                            undefined) (crypto.erl, line 516)
           
And in Erlang specification is allowed ecdh to use on keys generating.

Comment: OK, right, and what if you don't perform the hashing beforehand, i.e. input `Mesage` instead of  `Hash`into `crypto:sign`? It seems the parameter should be of type `binary()`, but you'll never know.

Comment: thx for you help: here is my result: Signature = crypto:sign(ecdsa, sha512, Mesage, PrivKeyOut).
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  crypto:pkey_sign_nif/5
        called as crypto:pkey_sign_nif(ecdsa,sha512,"testmessage",
                                       <<138,62,235,104,108,232,201,90,229,198,
                                         1,123,59,99,183,51,133,128,127,160,
                                         244,67,146,113,48,...>>,
                                       )
     in call from crypto:sign/5 (crypto.erl, line 433)

Comment: Hmm, `digest.binary()` should be accepted as well, so the double hashing is probably not the case. One thing I noticed is that the order of arguments is unclear in the API, could you switch `Hash` and `sha512` around? The order of the argument list and description is different in the API. Because I don't see any issue otherwise in the call.

Comment: Signature = crypto:sign(ecdsa, Hash, sha512, PrivKeyOut).
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  crypto:pkey_sign_nif/5
        called as crypto:pkey_sign_nif(ecdsa,
                                       <<1,216,98,78,245,111,176,233,114
                                       sha512,
                                       [])
     in call from crypto:sign/5 (crypto.erl, line 433)

Comment: I can't think any more, but thanks for your help

Comment: You're welcome, sorry I couldn't find it either. Take a step back and restart debugging later on. Maybe check for bugs and mention the precise library / runtime version.

Comment: I tried with other versions of ec and sha256 and sha128, the same result.

Comment: The hash values are handled identically for ECDSA, good try but that's unlikely to be it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

- The 4th argument of `crypto:sign/4` is called `Key`, but if you check the [type spec](https://erldocs.com/19.0/crypto/crypto.html?i=0&search=crypto:s#sign/4), it in fact takes an `[ecdh_private(), ecdh_params()]` list (in case of using the `ecdsa` algorithm at least).
- If you calculate the `Hash` yourself, the third argument shall be `{digest, Hash}`. Otherwise you will sign the hash of the message hash. You can also pass the plain message to the function, but in that case it has to be a binary, not a string.

This is how to fix these problems:

```
EcdhParams = crypto:ec_curve(secp521r1),
{PublicKey, PrivKeyOut} = crypto:generate_key(ecdh, EcdhParams),
Message = <<"testmessage">>,
crypto:sign(ecdsa, sha512, Message, [PrivKeyOut, EcdhParams]).
```

Or, in case you need the `Hash` later and/or you get `Message` as a string, this would also work:

```
EcdhParams = crypto:ec_curve(secp521r1),
{PublicKey, PrivKeyOut} = crypto:generate_key(ecdh, EcdhParams),
Message = "testmessage",
Hash = crypto:hash(sha512, Message),
crypto:sign(ecdsa, sha512, {digest, Hash}, [PrivKeyOut, EcdhParams]).
```

Comment: thx, this is the solution for my problem, I am beginner in erlang :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found old erlang bugs, these show that elliptic curve cipher suites are no completely implemented.
Here URLs:

http://erlang.2086793.n4.nabble.com/Incomplete-Elliptic-Curve-Cipher-Suites-in-R16B01-and-R16B02-td4692857.html
http://erlang-bugs.erlang.narkive.com/YNWGZ1F2/incomplete-elliptic-curve-cipher-suites-in-r16b01-and-r16b02

I would use the libsodium library for my tests:

https://github.com/jlouis/enacl

Thx